# Using subqueries and data - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to use subquery and at the same time use data in values when Inserting in mysqli?

```
insert into articles(description) values('Information');
insert into blogs(blog, article_id) values('example.com/', SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: Hint: No need for `SELECT` when calling a function

Comment: Nothing happened shows error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Simply wrap the subquery in parenthesis. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE articles (id int not null primary key, description varchar(50));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

CREATE TABLE blogs (id int not null primary key, blog varchar(50), article_id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

INSERT INTO articles (description) VALUES ('Information');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)

INSERT INTO blogs (blog, article_id) VALUES ('example.com/', (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()));
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
```

But as [@Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka) suggested in the comments above, in this case, you do not even need a subquery. This would have worked:

```
INSERT INTO blogs (blog, article_id) VALUES ('example.com/', LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `insert...select` instead.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

So it would be something like

`insert into blogs(...) select 'example.com/', last_insert_id()`